# Converting 'time values' stored in a tuple into 24 hours format

Tags: python, time, tuples

Suppose you have a tuple (Hours, minutes) and you want to convert it into 24 hours format hh:mm:ss. Assuming the seconds will always be 0. Eg. (14,0) will be 14:00:00 and (15,0) will be 15:00:00.

So far this is my sketchy way of coming close to the answer:

```
start_time = (14, 0)
st = ''

for num in start_time:
num = str(num)
if len(num) == 2:
    st += num
else:
    
    st += str(num) + '00'
print(st)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problems with your current approach:

- you're not using any `:` character. After each iteration, check if it's the last by considering the index in your for-loop. If it's not, append a `:` character.
- if `len(num) == 1`, you're inserting two trailing zeros, when it should be one leading zero.

Refactored code:

```
start_time = (14, 0)
st = ''

# `i` will store the index for each iteration
for i, num in enumerate(start_time):
    num = str(num)

    if len(num) == 2:
        st += num
    else:
        # If the number of digits is not 2, append a leading '0'
        st += '0' + num
        
    # If it's not the last number in the tuple
    if i < len(start_time) - 1:
        st += ':'
    else:
        st += ':00'
        
print(st)
```

This will output the expected value.

An alternative and compact way of doing this:

```
def time(t):
    #      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv   Join the mapped values to a single string using `:`
    #               vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv    Map this function to each value in this new tuple
    #                   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvv               Create a function that adds two trailing zero to a value
    #                                    vvvvvvvv     Create a new tuple with a trailing zero
    return ':'.join(map('{:02d}'.format, t + (0,)))

print(time((14, 0)))
print(time((15, 0)))
```

Comment: Thank you so much! :) Understood your first answer! But for the compact one I think I need to go and read up more hahaha

Answer (score 0):

I know you're probably just training on strings but if you want to create proper datetime objects use the datetime module:

```
from datetime import datetime

def create_time(x: tuple):
    return datetime.strptime(f"2021-11-03 {x[0]}:{x[1]}", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
                            #   ^^^^^^^^ you can set the date if needed
print(create_time((14, 15)))
```

Output:

```
2021-11-03 14:15:00
```

If you want only time just use the `.time()` method:

```
from datetime import datetime

def create_time(x: tuple):
    return datetime.strptime(f"{x[0]}:{x[1]}", "%H:%M").time()
print(create_time((14, 15)))
```

Output:

```
14:15:00
```

Comment: I see but I am looking to just get the time, don't need the date. Is it possible to call just the time?

Comment: Sure! I updated my answer!